# How to fill up datagridview cells based on other cell IDs?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

I have an Access database that has name ID-s in a column and I filled up the first column with those ID-s (38, 51, 88) and what I want to do is based on those ID-s I want to fill up the last selected column with some other data that are in the Access database but in another table.

For example, ID 38 would give me a price or a name in that row.

[image]

I tried it a lot of times but couldn't find a solution and I don't know If I have to use SQL for this or something else.

I got the needed SQL code but I don't know how to use it for the datagridview.

I have used something like that to fill up combo boxes like this:

```
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();

            connection.ConnectionString = "the connection string";

        connection.Open();

        string query2 = "SELECT Name From Names";
        command.CommandText = query2;

        OleDbDataReader reader2 = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader2.Read())
        {
            Combobox1.Items.Add(reader2["Name"].ToString());
        }
        connection.Close();
```

And now I think I should make an if statement where it checks if the 38 ID is in the DataGridView, then fill the other cell with the value in the same row of the Access table.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to populate the datagridview with the corresponding Price and Name that from another table?

Here is a demo you can refer to.

```
private void btnSetPriceName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constr = @"connection string";

    // create sql string
    StringBuilder strSQL = new StringBuilder();
    strSQL.Append("select Price, Name from PriceName where ");

    for(int i = 0;i< dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1;i++)
    {
        // get Id from string, like "38/1/R"
        string Id = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Split('/')[0];
        if (i == 0)
            strSQL.Append("Id = " + Id);
        else
            strSQL.Append("or Id = " + Id);
    }

    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(constr))
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand (strSQL.ToString(), conn);
        conn.Open();
        try
        {
            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader != null && reader.HasRows)
            {
                int rowindex = 0;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // Set Price/Name column value
                    dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells["Price"].Value = reader[0].ToString().Trim();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells["Name"].Value = reader[1].ToString().Trim();
                    rowindex++;
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nError:\n{0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```